# Show div if array's not visible in Angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I want to show a div if NOT data.success. Length of `userSet` is always more than 0. 
Basically I want to show a message if there is no search result
Here what I've got so far. thanks

html

```
      <ion-card *ngFor="let item of userSet | search : terms; let i = index">
      ....
      </ion-card>
       <div [(ngModel)]="data" ngShow="data">
       show this if no object is visible
       </div>
```

.ts file

```
       export class SearchPage {
       data: boolean;

       constructor(
    private sanitizer: DomSanitizer,
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public common: CommonModule,
    public userData: UserData,
    private alertCtrl: AlertController
    ) {
        this.searchSet();
     }  


     searchSet(){
    this.userData.searchUser()
    .map(res => res.json())
    .subscribe(data => {

        if (data.success) {
            this.userSet = data.searchDetails;// then it is uid_fk
            this.data = false;
        }
        else {
            this.data = true;
        }
    }); 
}
```

I am getting No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to declare userSet:

```
export class SearchPage {
   data: boolean;
   userSet:any;
```

`ngShow` is an angularJS syntax. you need to use `ngIf`:

```
   <div *ngIf="data">
   show this if no object is visible
   </div>
```

Comment: i am getting data is undefined

Comment: add *ngIf will help you. Also you declared variable in ts file.

Comment: that doesnt work. am i getting the data variable correct?

Comment: i did declare it userSet: any=[];